# Android: editText should automatically get the GeoLocations as suggestions

Tags: android, google-maps

[image: **Location of Dominos Pizza getting populated as suggestions automatically**]

I want an editText which will show locations from GoogleMaps as suggestions whenever I type in some name of the location.

Comment: it is not `EditText` what you are looking for but  `AutoCompleteTextView`

Comment: Here is what you want http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/android/android-google-places-autocomplete-api-example/

Comment: Thanks alot both of you. I will try it out.

Comment: @HiteshKamani I looked into the code which you sent me. I am totally not able to get the output. Can you help me with doing a simple AutoComplete TextView with Location Suggestions. It would be a great help

Comment: @SuryaBadrinath. What exactly the problem you are facing? can you explain in details. so that I can help you in details.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31655707/autocompletetextview-is-not-getting-the-suggestions-from-google-places-api..I have updated my code and error here. @HiteshKamani ,,,,,,,,,, Can you look into the link?

Comment: have you have enabled your google place api key in console?

Comment: Yes, I have added that in my code and manifest too.