# AutoCompleteTextView is not getting the suggestions from Google Places API

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2, google-places-api

This is my code to get the Places suggestions from Google Places API. But it is showing some error like "Cannot connect to Google Places API". I have given the proper error which I am getting at the bottom of this code.

I just need an AutoCompleteTextView to be populated with GeoLocations. For example, if the user types in "Deh", suggestions starting from Deh should appear right away,like, "Dehradun, India"

```
 public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

        Button selectRoute;
        private static final String LOG_TAG = "Google Places Autocomplete";
        private static final String PLACES_API_BASE = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place";
        private static final String TYPE_AUTOCOMPLETE = "/autocomplete";
        private static final String OUT_JSON = "/json";

        private static final String API_KEY = "My API Key";


        AutoCompleteTextView home;
        RadioButton yes, no;

        Spinner location, facility;



        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


            StrictMode.setVmPolicy(new StrictMode.VmPolicy.Builder().detectAll().penaltyLog()
                    .penaltyDeath().build());
            selectRoute = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
            home = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.autoCompleteTextView);


            home.setAdapter(new GooglePlacesAutocompleteAdapter(this, R.layout.list));
            home.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                    String str = (String) adapterView.getItemAtPosition(i);
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, str, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
            home.setThreshold(1);


        }


            @Override
            public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

                int id = item.getItemId();

                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
            }

            //____________________________________________________________________________________

        public static ArrayList autocomplete(String input) {
            ArrayList resultList = null;

            HttpURLConnection conn = null;
            StringBuilder jsonResults = new StringBuilder();
            try {
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(PLACES_API_BASE + TYPE_AUTOCOMPLETE + OUT_JSON);
                sb.append("?key=" + API_KEY);

                sb.append("&input=" + URLEncoder.encode(input, "utf8"));

                URL url = new URL(sb.toString());
                conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                InputStreamReader in = new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream());

                int read;
                char[] buff = new char[1024];
                while ((read = in.read(buff)) != -1) {
                    jsonResults.append(buff, 0, read);
                }
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Error processing Places API URL", e);
                return resultList;
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Error connecting to Places API", e);
                return resultList;
            } finally {
                if (conn != null) {
                    conn.disconnect();
                }
            }

            try {

                JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonResults.toString());
                JSONArray predsJsonArray = jsonObj.getJSONArray("predictions");


                resultList = new ArrayList(predsJsonArray.length());
                for (int i = 0; i < predsJsonArray.length(); i++) {
                    System.out.println(predsJsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("description"));
                    System.out.println("============================================================");
                    resultList.add(predsJsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("description"));
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Cannot process JSON results", e);
            }

            return resultList;
        }

        class GooglePlacesAutocompleteAdapter extends ArrayAdapter implements Filterable {
            private ArrayList resultList;

            public GooglePlacesAutocompleteAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId) {
                super(context, textViewResourceId);
            }

            @Override
            public int getCount() {
                return resultList.size();
            }

            /*@Override
            public String getItem(int index) {
                return resultList.get(index);
            }*/

            @Override
            public Filter getFilter() {
                Filter filter = new Filter() {
                    @Override
                    protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
                        FilterResults filterResults = new FilterResults();
                        if (constraint != null) {

                            resultList = autocomplete(constraint.toString());


                            filterResults.values = resultList;
                            filterResults.count = resultList.size();
                        }
                        return filterResults;
                    }

                    @Override
                    protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
                        if (results != null && results.count > 0) {
                            notifyDataSetChanged();
                        } else {
                            notifyDataSetInvalidated();
                        }
                    }
                };
                return filter;
            }
        }
```

This is the error which I am getting.

```
1691-1709/? E/Google Places Autocomplete﹕ Error connecting to Places API
    java.net.ConnectException: failed to connect to maps.googleapis.com/74.125.130.95 (port 443): connect failed: ETIMEDOUT (Connection timed out)
            at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:114)
            at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:192)
            at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:459)
            at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:843)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.Platform.connectSocket(Platform.java:131)
            at com.android.okhttp.Connection.connect(Connection.java:101)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:294)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendSocketRequest(HttpEngine.java:255)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:206)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:345)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:296)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:179)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:246)
            at com.mycompany.com.shareadrive.MainActivity.autocomplete(MainActivity.java:143)
            at com.mycompany.com.shareadrive.MainActivity$GooglePlacesAutocompleteAdapter$1.performFiltering(MainActivity.java:207)
            at android.widget.Filter$RequestHandler.handleMessage(Filter.java:234)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
     Caused by: libcore.io.ErrnoException: connect failed: ETIMEDOUT (Connection timed out)
            at libcore.io.Posix.connect(Native Method)
            at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.connect(BlockGuardOs.java:85)
            at libcore.io.IoBridge.connectErrno(IoBridge.java:127)
            at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:112)
            at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:192)
            at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:459)
            at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:843)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.Platform.connectSocket(Platform.java:131)
            at com.android.okhttp.Connection.connect(Connection.java:101)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:294)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendSocketRequest(HttpEngine.java:255)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:206)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:345)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:296)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:179)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:246)
            at com.mycompany.com.shareadrive.MainActivity.autocomplete(MainActivity.java:143)
            at com.mycompany.com.shareadrive.MainActivity$GooglePlacesAutocompleteAdapter$1.performFiltering(MainActivity.java:207)
            at android.widget.Filter$RequestHandler.handleMessage(Filter.java:234)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
```

This is the updated Log error which I am getting.

```
E/Google Places Autocomplete﹕ Error connecting to Places API
    java.net.SocketTimeoutException: failed to connect to maps.googleapis.com/74.125.200.95 (port 443) after 15000ms
            at libcore.io.IoBridge.connectErrno(IoBridge.java:159)
            at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:112)
            at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:192)
            at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:459)
            at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:843)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.Platform.connectSocket(Platform.java:131)
            at com.android.okhttp.Connection.connect(Connection.java:101)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:294)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendSocketRequest(HttpEngine.java:255)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:206)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:345)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:296)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:179)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:246)
            at com.mycompany.com.shareadrive.MainActivity.autocomplete(MainActivity.java:136)
            at com.mycompany.com.shareadrive.MainActivity$GooglePlacesAutocompleteAdapter$1.performFiltering(MainActivity.java:199)
            at android.widget.Filter$RequestHandler.handleMessage(Filter.java:234)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
07-28 03:32:05.900    1785-1829/? W/Filter﹕ An exception occured during performFiltering()!
    java.lang.NullPointerException
            at com.mycompany.com.shareadrive.MainActivity$GooglePlacesAutocompleteAdapter$1.performFiltering(MainActivity.java:203)
            at android.widget.Filter$RequestHandler.handleMessage(Filter.java:234)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
```

Comment: Please check your internet connection, might be down.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just tested your code that builds the url, and it looks fine, so that is not the problem.

You're probably getting a timeout from a slow connection, try setting the timeout on your HttpURLConnection:

```
conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
conn.setConnectTimeout(15000); //added
```

Also, note that if you haven't done so already, you will need to execute your network operation in a background thread, using an AsyncTask would be good for a short operation like this.

**Edit:**

I just ran a condensed version of your original code, and it worked just fine for me.

I used a Browser Key for the API key, and ran the `autocomplete()` method in an AsyncTask, and used "San Francisco" hard coded for the test.

Here is the full Activity class code that I used:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    Button testButton;
    TextView results;
    private static final String LOG_TAG = "PlacesAPI";
    private static final String PLACES_API_BASE = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place";
    private static final String TYPE_AUTOCOMPLETE = "/autocomplete";
    private static final String OUT_JSON = "/json";

    private static final String API_KEY = "my-api-key-here";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        results = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.result);

        testButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);

        testButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                new GetAutocompleteAsync().execute();
            }
        });
    }

    class GetAutocompleteAsync extends AsyncTask<String, String, ArrayList<String>>{

        @Override
        protected ArrayList<String> doInBackground(String... params) {

            ArrayList<String> results = autocomplete("San Francisco");
            return results;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<String> resultArrayList) {
            if (resultArrayList != null) {
                results.setText(resultArrayList.toString());
            }
        }

    }


    public static ArrayList autocomplete(String input) {
        ArrayList resultList = null;

        HttpURLConnection conn = null;
        StringBuilder jsonResults = new StringBuilder();
        try {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(PLACES_API_BASE + TYPE_AUTOCOMPLETE + OUT_JSON);
            sb.append("?key=" + API_KEY);

            sb.append("&input=" + URLEncoder.encode(input, "utf8"));

            URL url = new URL(sb.toString());
            conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            InputStreamReader in = new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream());

            int read;
            char[] buff = new char[1024];
            while ((read = in.read(buff)) != -1) {
                jsonResults.append(buff, 0, read);
            }
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Error processing API URL", e);
            return resultList;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Error connecting to Places API", e);
            return resultList;
        } finally {
            if (conn != null) {
                conn.disconnect();
            }
        }

        try {

            JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonResults.toString());
            JSONArray predsJsonArray = jsonObj.getJSONArray("predictions");


            resultList = new ArrayList(predsJsonArray.length());
            for (int i = 0; i < predsJsonArray.length(); i++) {
                System.out.println(predsJsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("description"));
                System.out.println("============================================================");
                resultList.add(predsJsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("description"));
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Cannot process JSON results", e);
        }

        return resultList;
    }
}
```

Here are the resulting logs:

```
I/System.out﹕ San Francisco, CA, United States
I/System.out﹕ ============================================================
I/System.out﹕ San Francisco, San Antonio, TX, United States
I/System.out﹕ ============================================================
I/System.out﹕ San Francisco International Airport, San Francisco, CA, United States
I/System.out﹕ ============================================================
I/System.out﹕ San Francisco County, CA, United States
I/System.out﹕ ============================================================
I/System.out﹕ San Francisco De La Espada, Espada Road, San Antonio, TX, United States
I/System.out﹕ ============================================================
I/System.out﹕ San Francisco, CA, United States
I/System.out﹕ ============================================================
I/System.out﹕ San Francisco, San Antonio, TX, United States
I/System.out﹕ ============================================================
I/System.out﹕ San Francisco International Airport, San Francisco, CA, United States
I/System.out﹕ ============================================================
I/System.out﹕ San Francisco County, CA, United States
I/System.out﹕ ============================================================
I/System.out﹕ San Francisco De La Espada, Espada Road, San Antonio, TX, United States
I/System.out﹕ ============================================================
I/System.out﹕ San Francisco, CA, United States
I/System.out﹕ ============================================================
I/System.out﹕ San Francisco, San Antonio, TX, United States
I/System.out﹕ ============================================================
I/System.out﹕ San Francisco International Airport, San Francisco, CA, United States
I/System.out﹕ ============================================================
I/System.out﹕ San Francisco County, CA, United States
I/System.out﹕ ============================================================
I/System.out﹕ San Francisco De La Espada, Espada Road, San Antonio, TX, United States
I/System.out﹕ ============================================================
```

Comment: InputStreamReader in = new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream());    It says there is an error in this line. Do you know why?

Comment: I still have errors in URL url = new URL(sb.toString());
                conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                InputStreamReader in = new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream());        and                                                                             resultList = autocomplete(constraint.toString());

Comment: @surya are you able to browse the Internet on your emulator?

Comment: Yes, that I am able to do. And anyway, it should work in Android device right, if the code is correct. I have errors coming on the above lines. Am not getting the JSON result from the Google places API. Also, do you know how to add SHA 1 key to the google API console. I have created a key and left it blank so that any android application can utilize it. Is that okay?

Comment: @surya This is the places web service API, so you should be using a server key.  However, I don't think that is your problem, even though the documentation says an Android key won't work, it does work if you keep the sha1/package field blank. I'll test out your code tomorrow just to make sure it's correct.

Comment: Sure, that would be great. Thank you so much for your valuable time @Daniel. Till then, I will keep on checking it and will let you know once I finished. Thanks again.

Comment: @SuryaBadrinath I just updated the answer.  Your code for the API works fine under normal conditions.  Make sure that you're running your network operations in a background thread, in my example I used an AsyncTask.

Comment: Thank you so much buddy. You saved my day. This code is working very clearly

Answer (score 1):

FYI:Avoid **`ActionBarActivity`**.Its deprecated .Try this [Android – AutoCompleteTextView with Google Places Autocomplete API](http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/android-autocompletetextview-with-google-places-autocomplete-api/)

Comment: I tried it already, it doesn't work as I expected. The AutoCompleteTextView doesn't get the suggestions at all.

Comment: @SuryaBadrinath How is it possible . Did you follow its step by step approach ? Because of in here it works fine

Comment: I guess I followed the steps properly. Anyway, I will definitely try it out once more and reply back. One more doubt I have...... Does Emulator has Map support, because I installed Google Play services and also added the dependencies in Studio respectively. Any idea if anything else to be done?